# How do I programmatically delete labels/buttons/textfields?

Tags: objective-c

I am making an app where you have to enter your name. Then when you press the go button, the text field, button, and text vanish. But I don't really know how to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you just need to vanish you can make it hidden

```
yourButton.hidden = YES;
```

or

```
yourButton.alpha = 0.0;
```

or you can remove it like

```
[yourButton removeFromSuperview];
```

Answer (score 1):

Put all UIButton, UITextView, UITextField, UIImageView in one view and let that view get hidden when you click Go button. This way you don't have multiple hidden statement for each UIButton, UITextView, UITextField, UIImageView, etc.

So final statement would be

```
yourView.hidden = YES;
```